# reduce size of pretrained deep learning model for feature generation

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am using an pretrained model in Keras to generate features for a set of images:

```
model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
train_data = model.predict(data).reshape(data.shape[0],-1)
```

However, I have a lot of images and the Imagenet model outputs 131072 features (columns) for each image.

With 200k images I would get an array of `(200000, 131072)` which is too large to fit into memory.

More importantly, I need to save this array to disk and it would take 100 GB of space when saved as `.npy` or `.h5py`

I could circumvent the memory problem by feeding only batches of like 1000 images and saving them to disk, but not the disk space problem.

How can I make the model smaller without losing too much information?

**update**

as the answer suggested I include the next layer in the model as well:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet')
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=base_model.get_layer('avg_pool').output)
```

this reduced the output to `(200000, 2048)`

**update 2**:

another interesting solution may be the `bcolz` package to reduce size of numpy arrays  https://github.com/Blosc/bcolz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two solutions to your problem:

1. Apply a `model = AveragePooling2D((8, 8), strides=(8, 8))(model)` where `model` is an `InceptionV3` object you loaded (without top). This is the next step in `InceptionV3` architecture - so one may easily assume - that these features still hold loads of discriminatory clues.
2. Apply a some kind of dimensionality reduction (e.g. like `PCA`) on a sample of data and reduce the dimensionality of all data to get the reasonable file size.

Comment: 1. is actually a pretty simple solution, and it brings a good reduction. 2. is not feasible, I tried that already. It also does not make sense to calculate PCA for a first batch of 1000 images and then subsequently transform the other image batches with the same values.