# Universal Sentence Encoder, reduce vector dimensionality

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, vector, nlp

I am successfully converting documents using [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3) module available on TensorFlow hub.

The output of each document is a 512 dimensional vector, however this is too large for my application and I would like to reduce the dimensionality, which the module itself does not provide.

I can see a few options:

- Use another package with a lower dimensionality output.
- Use something such as PCA or tSNE to reduce the dimensions.

The problem with using PCA or tSNE is that this needs to be fit to the data of many example vectors - this would mean as new documents arrived and had been converted to a 512-dim vector, I would need to keep fitting another model, and then updating the old document vectors - this would be a huge issue in my application.

Are there any other dimensionality reduction techniques which can operate on a single data point?

Comment: just a thought, might be silly : cant you just do a linear (or non-linear also) mapping to a lower dimension using a `dense` layer ?

Comment: That involves learning the layer, similar to a PCA or tSNE it seems to me.

Comment: sure but you can just throw in a `dense` layer after you get 512 dim vector and just let it train along the whole model. Instead in a PCA you would collect all your 512 document vectors and run PCA on it, but here you just train the layer along the `encoder-decoder` model. am i making sense ? :/

Comment: Not sure I get this - I need to reduce the dims, and store this vector for each document to be used later as a feature for other models - I am not sure what this layer would be learning as we have nothing to optimise.

Comment: ok so i just saw that you are using a pre-trained encoder. i think the `dense` layer doesnt need to learn anything its just a way of representing your input data. you can think this in a transfer-learning style where all your encoder wghts have been trained and you just use a dense layer with random weights in the end to represent your data.

Comment: if you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573986/reduce-size-of-pretrained-deep-learning-model-for-feature-generation) : it talks about this same approach. The pretrained weights already hold lot of power to represent your docs and the last layer is just squashing them.

Comment: Hmm not sure - if you are saying the layer has not learnt anything - then it is randomly reducing the dimensions - so in essence I may as well just take the first 100 components of each vector. Am I missing something?

Comment: try this: attach a dense layer on top of pretrained encoder. Also make a `decoder net` to train your dense layer. measure the loss between 512 dim output vector of `decoder` and 512 dim input vector of `dense` layer. After training throw away the decoder and use only the encoder to compress 512 dim vector. Remember to freeze the pretrained layers. decoder will try to backpropagate error bw original and reconstructed 512 dim vector which trains only the dense layer. this way you have encoder which reconstructs lower dim representation of 512 input vector.

Comment: also, you can write your decoder in `transformer` style architecture using `attention layers`, this way you can avoid the hassle of writing lstm based decoders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"UMAP supports adding new points to an existing embedding via the standard sklearn transform method." [UMAP](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) is the winner for dimensionality reduction in every way, speed, accuracy, and theoretical foundation.

Comment: Thanks @Sam H. but I was really interested in finding a way if possible to reduce the dimensions without "learning" on the data first - is that at all possible??

Comment: If there were a way to embed N dimensional space in D dimensional space, for N>D, without losing any information, the answer would be yes. But there is not. That's the thing with dimensionality reduction. There's a model because it has to learn what lower dimensional submanifold the data live on. But, you're over estimating the cost of adding a learned model. If you train it on a representative sample of your data, you may only need to retrain it (or in the case of UMAP, update it) rarely.